# Issues /w Exoside Quad Remesher closer to points with less vertices?

Tags: remesh

[image: Picture is example of what remesher is doing to mesh of tentacles.]

For the life of me I can't figure out how to remesh these high res tentacles it just keeps doing this. toggled all sorts of options in the remesher. Any suggestions or do I h need to make the tips of the tentales more "flat" or contain more face for it to work? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but this Q&A site is here to help with problems with Blender and its built-in addons. We really can't help with third-party addons.

Comment: Since this is a paid add-on, please contact [Quad Remesher support](https://exoside.com/company/contact/). Thank you for your understanding!